# How is the locale of a C program set to the "C" locale?

Tags: c, linux

> A C program inherits its locale environment variables when it starts up. This happens automatically. However, these variables do not automatically control the locale used by the library functions, **because ANSI C says that all programs start by default in the standard `"C"` locale**.

I have [read that a C program must have the C locale when started](https://web.archive.org/web/20180514054122/http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_19.html#SEC323), so the C program must do something like this when started:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```

But how does this line of code end up in the C program? Does the compiler add it for me?

Comment: It happens during program startup.  Either the compiler emits code, or there is code in a library called during startup.

Comment: I read "default" to mean "in the absence of a call to `setlocale`"

Comment: Wouldn't this be implementation dependent?

Comment: The library is required to set the locale as if it contained that line, just as it is required to make sure that `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are initialized correctly, as if with an appropriate call to `fopen()`.  You can set an implementation-defined alternative locale by adding `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` to the start of your program.  Any other value is not specified by the C standard, and falls into the 'implementation-defined behaviour' category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not modify the source code and add an explicit call to `setlocale()` to your main program.  Rather, the implementation (the combination of compiler and library) is required to ensure that the program behaves 'as if' there was a call to `setlocale()` at the start.

There are many other aspects of program behaviour that the implementation must ensure work correctly too.  For example, it must ensure that `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are set up correctly — you don't have to open those streams explicitly in the `main()` program because the library ensures that they are set up before `main()` is called.  On POSIX systems, the startup code ensures that the `environ` global variable is set appropriately.  You can see a lot of the relevant information in the POSIX specification of [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html), including:

> For the new process image, the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")
> ```
>
> shall be executed at start-up.

The C standard also says much the same thing [C11 §7.11.1.1 The `setlocale` function](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.1.1p4) says:

> At program startup, the equivalent of
>
> ```
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
> ```
>
> is executed.

The details of how any specific implementation achieves the effect are inherently implementation-specific, but it typically is achieved by initializing selected global variables with the appropriate correct values.  The standard doesn't say how the implementation must achieve the effect; it simply says that it must achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

This is platform specific. On a GNU/Linux system, the locale is managed by glibc, which stores the settings in a global variable `_nl_global_locale`. To meet the requirements for the default setting, it's simply [initialized with the values for `C`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/global-locale.c;h=6cdc41f527c1f918b9d550d7f1723289ac496e00;hb=HEAD#l39):

```
struct __locale_struct _nl_global_locale attribute_hidden =
  {
    .__locales =
    {
#define DEFINE_CATEGORY(category, category_name, items, a) \
      [category] = &_nl_C_##category,
#include "categories.def"
#undef  DEFINE_CATEGORY
    },
    .__names =
    {
      [LC_ALL] = _nl_C_name,
#define DEFINE_CATEGORY(category, category_name, items, a) \
      [category] = _nl_C_name,
#include "categories.def"
#undef  DEFINE_CATEGORY
    },
    .__ctype_b = (const unsigned short int *) _nl_C_LC_CTYPE_class + 128,
    .__ctype_tolower = (const int *) _nl_C_LC_CTYPE_tolower + 128,
    .__ctype_toupper = (const int *) _nl_C_LC_CTYPE_toupper + 128
  };
```

There's no need to actually call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");`  since all the settings are already pointing to the C locale through this initialization.